# Установил VS 2010, не создается проект

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, проекты

Не могу нажать кнопку OK при создании проекта, она просто прозрачная, что делать?

Comment: В университете требуют, чтобы мы писали именно в этой версии

Comment: Ну такого быть не может, скрин хоть покажите